# Bean validation not working until JPA entity is merged

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, bean-validation, wildfly

When the backing bean of the Facelet invokes `setLastName("Test!!!")` no ConstraintViolationException is thrown, although the non-alpha chars are clearly present in the method argument.

I set a breakpoint to verify that setLastName was being invoked and I observed the JPA entity's lastName value change.  Validation should fail immediately, yes?  It's not.

Later, when it's time to persist the changes, when EntityManager#merge is invoked, the ConstraintViolationException is thrown.

> List of constraint violations:[
>   ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.spacesandletters',
>   propertyPath=lastName, rootBeanClass=class
>   foo.bar.business.model.entity.authenticate.User,
>   messageTemplate='error.spacesandletters'}]

```
private String lastName;

@Column(name="lastname", nullable=false, length=40)
@Size(max=40)
@NotNull
@Basic(optional=false)
@Pattern(regexp="[A-Za-z ]*", message="error.spacesandletters")
public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }

public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
```

So I know that validation is available and that it is working at JPA pre-persist.  But for some reason it's not working at the moment User#setLastName is first invoked via the backing bean.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT #1:

I should have mentioned that my ChangePasswordBean works just fine with the following two custom annotations.

```
@NotEmpty @Password private String password1;
@NotEmpty @Password private String password2;
```

But in this case the backing bean's fields are annotated.  Whereas in the example above the backing bean is pointing to the JPA entity whose getters are annotated.

EDIT #2:

After reading BalusC's reference to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264868/bean-validation-skipped-on-cdi-managed-jsf-controller/) in which he was thinking that the problem might be related to a [known Mojarra bug that was fixed in v. 2.2.7](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183) I upgraded to Mojarra 2.2.8-01.  Here's the entry in the Wildfly startup log:

> 17:41:51,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [mojarra-2.2.8-01, main]

Unfortunately, the problem I've described has not gone away.  Bean validation annotations on the JPA entity are not working whereas bean validation annotations on the JSF managed bean are working.

Comment: Just a wild guess - would moving annotations from get to set (or even better - to field itself) change anything?

Comment: if you do not have @Validation in your controller, validation will just happen in Persist/Merge level. I am not familiar with Facelet and JSF,  but there should be something similar with Spring-MVC in terms of validation.

Comment: @pmp: @Validation?  No such thing in javax.validation.constraints.  P.S. I'm not using Spring.

Comment: @Deltharis can't put annotations on getter; it's against the Bean Validation spec.  Moving to field itself had better not change anything, else the spec. is not being followed by the container.

Comment: Which Mojarra version? Which container impl/version? Are you using JRebel? In any case, this is perhaps a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264868/bean-validation-skipped-on-cdi-managed-jsf-controller/

Comment: No, not using JRebel.  primefaces-5.0,
primefaces-extensions-2.0.0,
atmosphere-runtime-2.1.4,
Mojarra 2.2.6,
wildfly-8.1.0.Final

Comment: @Balusc my problem is the reverse of the problem indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264868/bean-validation-skipped-on-cdi-managed-jsf-controller/.  His JPA annotations (on PhysicalAsset) were working whereas his managed bean annotations (on PhysicalAssetListController) were not.  My JPA annotations are not working whereas my managed bean annotations are working.

Comment: You meant to say *"Bean validation annotations on JPA entity are not working whereas bean validation annotations on JSF managed bean are working"*, right?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Sorry for the confusion.  I've updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behaviour. If you relying on JPA event based validation, validation occurs at the pre-update event. There is no life cycle event available which would trigger at the change of a single field. And really this would only work with instrumented classes, since otherwise there would be no way to even intercept the setting of the value. Also, Bean Validation is in its core a framework to validate whole beans and its associations. So even if there is `validateValue` and `validateProperty` in the `Validation` API, the main validation routine is `validate` which takes a bean/object as parameter.

So to answer your question:

> Validation should fail immediately, yes?

No, it should not.

Do you really need a direct validation on calling the setter? There are ways to do this, but it would involve writing some custom code and you would either need to use a compile or runtime interception framework.

Comment: Yes need validation when user clicks button -- not later, when the entity is merged.  The ConstraintViolationException should be thrown when the backing bean's setter is invoked.  This all works fine on my other pages.  The difference being that this particular backing bean points to a JPA entity.  So the backing bean's getters/setters invoke the getters/setters on the entity beans.  Are you saying that I should be using two identical sets of annotations, one set on the entity bean and the other set on the backing bean?

Comment: I've edited my question with additional info.  Another backing bean whose fields are annotated validates just fine whereas the backing bean that points to the JPA is having problems.

Comment: I understand that you answered this while OP didn't use `[jsf]` tag, but the OP clearly told he used Facelets. JSF has indeed builtin support for performing Bean Validation during the validations phase, as expected by the OP. So your answer is fundamentally wrong and you should revise or remove it.